# Is there a way to make an NPN transistor activate when base voltage or current drops to zero?

Tags: transistors

I have the following DC circuit:

[image]

The intention is for an IR sensor (which operates at 5 volts) to activate a transistor to then let power flow to a 12v LED array.

The problem is the IR sensor that I have is a bit odd. When the sensor is NOT detecting anything, it outputs a 5v signal through the data output. When the sensor detects something, the data output drops to 0 volts. That is, the IR sensor appears to be normally closed.

As such, the whole circuit works opposite of what I want. When the sensor is not detecting anything, the 5V data signal activates the NPN (2A2222N) transistor, and the LED array is turned on. When the sensor detects something, the LED array turns off.

I would like this to be the opposite, such that the LED array is normally off and only turns on when the sensor detects something and the data signal drops to 0v.

Is there a way to configure this circuit to allow this? Do I need to use a PNP transistor, or is there a different component I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure this circuit to allow this? Do I need to use a PNP transistor, or is there a different component I need?

One approach is to add another transistor to act as an inverter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjzYvm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the input at V2

[image]

And here is the corresponding output current.

[image]

Note that there will be some small current through the LED array (typically in the nano-amps, but it could be more) when the input is 5V. That current *might* be enough to make the LED array glow slightly. Decreasing the value of R3 will help if needed. I added R4 because I don't know the specifics of your LED array. It may require a current limiting resistor, or it may have some current limiting circuitry already.

If your LED array requires more than, say 100 mA of current, you will need to reduce R2, so that it can supply enough base current to Q2. You may also need a larger Q2, and possibly a heat-sink. This circuit is just to get you started. I.e. you may need to tweak resistor values.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem! At first I tried to use one transistor as a "not gate" but the resistance I needed to avoid overpowering it made the LED array too dim. Using a second transistor as the not gate let me deliver full power to the LED array without issues. Thanks again!